# save() function in Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm using the Armadillo library in a C++ project (with Xcode) and I would like to create a .mat file containing matrix A (as in the code hereafter).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main ()
{

    mat A;
        A << 0.165300 << 0.454037 << 0.995795 << 0.124098 << 0.047084 << endr
        << 0.688782 << 0.036549 << 0.552848 << 0.937664 << 0.866401 << endr
        << 0.348740 << 0.479388 << 0.506228 << 0.145673 << 0.491547 << endr
        << 0.148678 << 0.682258 << 0.571154 << 0.874724 << 0.444632 << endr
        << 0.245726 << 0.595218 << 0.409327 << 0.367827 << 0.385736 << endr;

    cout << A << endl;

    bool status = A.save("test.mat", arma_ascii);

    if(status == true)
    {
        cout << "Save OK !" << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Problem with save" << endl << endl;
    }



    mat B;
    B.load("test.mat", arma_ascii);

    cout << B;
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, as you can see in the results below, except the fact that I cannot find the file "test.mat" anywhere :( ! It is supposed to be in the project's folder, but unfortunately this is not the case! Anyone have any idea to solve this issue?

```
   0.1653   0.4540   0.9958   0.1241   0.0471
   0.6888   0.0365   0.5528   0.9377   0.8664
   0.3487   0.4794   0.5062   0.1457   0.4915
   0.1487   0.6823   0.5712   0.8747   0.4446
   0.2457   0.5952   0.4093   0.3678   0.3857

Save OK !

   0.1653   0.4540   0.9958   0.1241   0.0471
   0.6888   0.0365   0.5528   0.9377   0.8664
   0.3487   0.4794   0.5062   0.1457   0.4915
   0.1487   0.6823   0.5712   0.8747   0.4446
   0.2457   0.5952   0.4093   0.3678   0.3857
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have problems with the function load() too. It always fail to read the file located in the project's folder.

Comment: can you search your drive to find the file? your working directory may set to something else

Comment: Yes, I already tried but without success !

Comment: Using  find / test.mat in the terminal window I get: test.mat: No such file or directory.     Could this problem be related to the installation/configuration of the Armadillo libraries in Xcode?

Comment: I didn't dare to edit your question in this case but to be sure: It is test.mat you are searching for not test.dat, right? Please edit your post accordingly because this is an important point.

Comment: Thanks @TobiMcNamobi ! It was a small mistake :) But I was searching at the correct file. So, the problem is still unsolved :(